# I want to set "post_type OR tax_query"

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I actually have a hook like this on **pre_get_post**:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_post_pre_get_posts');
function my_post_pre_get_posts($query)
{
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home()) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 3);

        //FILTERS
        $type = array();
        if(!empty($_GET['type'])) {
            $type = explode(',', $_GET['type']);
        }else {
            $type = array('post', 'testimonial', 'project');
        }
        $query->set('post_type', $type);

        //CATEGORIES
        if(!empty($_GET['category'])) {
            $category = explode(',', $_GET['category']);

            $args = array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
            );

            foreach ($category as $categorie) {
                array_push($args, 
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => $category
                    )
                );
            }
            $query->set('tax_query', $args);

        }
    }
}
```

With this, my home display **posts** and also two other custom post type: **"project" and "testimonials"**.

My posts have **categories** (but project and testimonials haven't it) and I would like to filters them with it. But I don't want that when I filter with the taxonomy its hide the project and testimonials results.

**So instead of have an "AND" relation between post_type and taxonomy I want an "OR" relation**. Do you think it's possible ? Do I have to rewrite the global $wpdb ?

Answer (score 0):

set 'relation' after your category loop alongside your 'tax_query' set

$query->tax_query->relation ='OR';